# MB_DETECT_ENCODING : how to detect english?

Tags: php, unicode

My website geting lot of spam in chinese, japanese & russian and others.

with the help of MB_DETECT_ENCODING, Iam able to detect all other languages --- but it is not detecting correctly english.

Any help is appreciated!!!

```
$str = 'As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable. As of PHP 5.5 it is possible to array dereference an array literal.';


$lang = array('EUC-CN','EUC-JP','EUC-KR','EUC-TW','GB18030','SJIS','UCS-2','UCS-2BE','UCS-2LE','UTF-32','eucJP-win','EUC-JP-2004','SJIS-2004','CP932','JIS','ISO-2022-JP','ISO-8859-1','ISO-8859-2','ISO-8859-3','ISO-8859-4','ISO-8859-5','ISO-8859-6','ISO-8859-7','ISO-8859-8','ISO-8859-9','ISO-8859-10','ISO-8859-13','ISO-8859-14','ISO-8859-15','ISO-8859-16','EUC-CN','CP936','HZ','EUC-TW','BIG-5','EUC-KR','UHC','ISO-2022-KR','CP866','KOI8-R','KOI8-U','CP850','JIS-ms','ISO-2022-JP-2004','CP50220','CP50220raw','CP50221','CP50222');

//print_r($lang);

$enc = mb_detect_encoding($str,$lang);
    echo 'enc : ' . $enc . '<br><br>';

if(mb_detect_encoding($str,$lang) !='ASCII'){ 
    //return  iconv("gbk","utf-8",$str); 
    echo 'you cant spam here';
}
```

Comment: you can't really detect "english". e.g. `Bonjour` and `Hello` are both identical as far as character sets are concerned - no accented characters, no funky diacritics, blah blah blah.

Comment: mb_detect_encoding is for detecting encoding only.  It's not even going to be effective blocking exotic character sets should the spammer decide to simply submit them in a unicode encoding.  Also what about valid English characters that ASCII doesn't support like £ or €?

Comment: Thanks guys... I am able to identify all languages and not English. But there must be someway to identify English thru unicode checks and block all those non-English inputs. eh???